# Keep Checkbox group items from wrapping?

Tags: xpages

I have a check box group with multiple items that may contain a space.  It is a horizontal check box.  What is happening is the items are wrapping where there is a space in the item.

How could I get them to not wrap?

Also how do I control the width?  I tried setting the width of the control and even placed it in a panel with the width set but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your stylesheet for the application:

```
.xspCheckBox { width: 500px; /* change to your preferred width */ }
.xspCheckBox td { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I think maybe I have too many items to be listed.  It is still trying to put them all on the same line. What I want is sort of like the columns feature for check boxes in Notes forms

Comment: It could be that I misunderstood your needs. Is this what you're looking for? http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2011/04/simple-trick-to-format-xpages-checkbox.html